# HTML5 canvas patterns

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I wrote the following code on my text editor:

```
!DOCTYPE html><html><head><script>

window.onload = function()
{
  canvas  = document.getElementById("canvasArea");
  context = canvas.getContext("2d");

  var smallIMage = new Image();
  smallImage.src = "https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/cardfight/images/8/89/De.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20130414214050";

  smallImage.onload = function()
  {
    context.shadowOffsetX  = 4;
    context.shadowOffsetY  = 4;
    context.shadowBlur     = 20;
    context.shadowColor    = "lavender";
    context.strokestyle    = "gray";
    context.lineWidth      = 1;

    var repeatPattern   = context.createPattern(smallImage, "repeat");
    var noRepeatPattern = context.createPattern(smallImage, "no-repeat");
    var repeatXPattern  = context.createPattern(smallImage, "repeat-x");
    var repeatYPattern  = context.createPattern(smallImage, "repeat-y");

    context.fillStyle = repeatPattern;
    context.fillRect   (125, 125, 325, 325);
    context.strokeRect (125, 125, 325, 325);
    context.fillStyle = noRepeatPattern;
    context.fillRect   (0, 0, 100, 100);
    context.strokeRect (0, 0, 100, 100);
    context.fillStyle = repeatXPattern;
    context.fillRect   (125, 0, 350, 100);
    context.strokeRect (125, 0, 350, 100);
    context.fillStyle = repeatYPattern;
    context.fillRect   (0, 125, 100, 350);
    context.strokeRect (0, 125, 100, 350);
  }
}
</script></head><body>
<div    style = "width:500px; height:500px; 
                 margin:0 auto; padding:5px;">
<canvas id    = "canvasArea" 
        width = "500" height = "500"
        style = "border:2px solid black">
Your browser doesn't currently support HTML5 canvas.
</canvas>
</div>    
</body>
</html>
```

This code s supposed to create a pattern from an online image, but it's not showing as the canvas is completely blank. Can you please tell me what I did wrong.

Comment: `smallIMage` should probably be `smallImage` with a small M. There are several other errors in the example here but that is the major one.

Answer (score 0):

There wasn't much wrong with your code apart from correcting a few spelling inconsistencies and defining the `new Image()` event handler before assigning it's `.src` property.  Also, remember to declare the `charset` of the document in the `head` section of the file.  E.G...

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    ... etc ...
</head>
```

Anyway, after a little editing the major components of your page look like this.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    var canvas  = document.getElementById("canvasArea"),
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
        smallImage = new Image();

    /* set canvas dimensions */
    canvas.width = canvas.height = 500;

    smallImage.addEventListener("load", function() {
        /* the image is bound to the
           function's 'this' property */
        var repeatPattern   = ctx.createPattern(this, "repeat"),
            noRepeatPattern = ctx.createPattern(this, "no-repeat"),
            repeatXPattern  = ctx.createPattern(this, "repeat-x"),
            repeatYPattern  = ctx.createPattern(this, "repeat-y");

        ctx.shadowOffsetX  = 4;
        ctx.shadowOffsetY  = 4;
        ctx.shadowBlur     = 20;
        ctx.shadowColor    = "rgb(230,230,250)";
        ctx.strokestyle    = "rgb(128,128,128)";
        ctx.lineWidth      = 1;

        ctx.fillStyle = repeatPattern;
        ctx.fillRect   (125, 125, 325, 325);
        ctx.strokeRect (125, 125, 325, 325);

        ctx.fillStyle = noRepeatPattern;
        ctx.fillRect   (0, 0, 100, 100);
        ctx.strokeRect (0, 0, 100, 100);

        ctx.fillStyle = repeatXPattern;
        ctx.fillRect   (125, 0, 350, 100);
        ctx.strokeRect (125, 0, 350, 100);

        ctx.fillStyle = repeatYPattern;
        ctx.fillRect   (0, 125, 100, 350);
        ctx.strokeRect (0, 125, 100, 350);

    }, !1);

    /* define Image.onload event handler
       before assigning Image.src */
    smallImage.src = "https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/cardfight/images/8/89/De.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20130414214050";

}, !1);
```

```css
body {
    background:rgb(90,90,110);
    padding:33px 0 }

#box {
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    background:rgb(50,50,70);
    margin:0 auto;
    box-shadow:0 0 0.25em 0.5em rgba(0,0,0,0.25) }

#canvasArea {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border:2px solid rgb(22,22,22) }
```

```html
<div id="box">
    <canvas id="canvasArea">
        Your browser doesn't currently support HTML5 canvas.
    </canvas>
</div>
```

BP ;)